# Owl Carousel 2 receiving item index from element with specific content

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

can anyone tell me how to receive item index from element with specific content inside

element?

My item looks like that:

```
<div class="item"><img style="position: relative; top: 80px; left: 0px; z-index: 7; width: 27px; height: 27px; opacity: 1!important;" src="someurl" /><img class="thumbimg" style="position: absolute; top: 12px; width: 100%; height: 136px;" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()) ?>" /><p style="position: relative; top: -25px;"><?php echo get_the_title() ?></p></div>
```

Comment: you want the index of `.item`..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**filter()** method lets you specify a criteria. Elements that do not match the criteria are removed from the selection, and those that match will be returned.This method is often used to narrow down the search for an element in a group of selected elements.Hope this is what u meant mate.. :)

```
$('.item').filter(function() {
    var text = $.trim($(this).find("p").text());
    if(text == "Testing")
    alert("Index = "+($(this).index()+1));
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fvstz46s/)

**FYI**

[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)